# Can't found modp package in Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, package

I start new application nodejs [in Github source](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx).

I start new thread like: `node test.js` in command line
I cannot found package modp in npm and bower.

This is my code:

```
describe('source',function(){it('should load',function(){X=require('modp');});});
```

It return fail is: `describe is not define`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don´t have mocha properly installed. describe is a method/key word inside the mocha test library.

```
npm install -g mocha
```

For testing you must use mocha command, node test.js is not correct for this purpose.

Comment: I've install mocha. And use command: `mocha or mocha test.js` but not successfull.

Comment: You can run any other test with success in that project? Mocha runs tests in "test" folder by default. As i said before node is raising a "describe is not define" i think that the error is not related with the modp require. You are running the test with node command and you should run it with mocha command.